# Can I get opportunityPartner records that have been deleted by using the query/queryAll method?

Tags: soql, api, soap

I need to get any opportunityPartner records that have been modified in some way, whether they have been deleted, created or updated, using the SOAP api. I actually need to know the opportunityIDs that they refer to. I can get created/updated partners by running a query, but that doesn't seem to pick up deleted records, even though I'm led to believe that queryAll brings back deleted records as well. I'm at a loss as to how I find out which opportunities have had partners deleted. As I said, I was hoping that the queryAll method would work, but testing this, it did not pick up any of the opportunityPartners that I had just deleted. (the isDeleted field on the result set was false for every record returned). The getDeleted() function is not going to help in this case because, as I said, I need to know the opportunityIDs, not the actual ID of the partner record.

Is this at all possible using any methods available to me in the SOAP Api?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the recycle bin is skipped for these records. So no way to retrieve them after deletion. Also the OpportunityPartner object does not support triggers or workflow'.

So there's really no other option than building your own custom opportunityPartner object, which will then have all the funtionality you need.